# Why can't I enter a city-state's territory?

Tags: civilization-5

In a recent game a certain city-state became angry with me, and from that point onward I could not enter the territory of the city-state, it showed it in red, just like trying to enter mountains or deep-ocean tiles in early game. This behavior persisted after the city-state returned to neutral state. It was never friends with me. I could enter the territories of other city-states just fine.

I've found [this thread on civfanatics](http://forums.civfanatics.com/showthread.php?p=10813659) where a user encountered the exact same phenomena, but the participants there could not find any explanation.

Is it a bug? If it isn't, why does this happen, how can I prevent it, and can I restore the ability to move through that territory?

Comment: I think I've seen this too.  My money is on bug.

Comment: The territory of neutral Powers is inviolable. - "[Rights and Duties of Neutral Powers and Persons in Case of War on Land (Hague V)](http://avalon.law.yale.edu/20th_century/hague05.asp)" (1907), Article 1

Comment: Have you tried declaring war? It sounds like this uppity city-state deserves what's coming to it.

Comment: Are they in an Alliance with a civilization you're at war with?

Comment: @jmee if they were, they'd automatically be in war with me...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I and a handful of other people on the Civfanatics forums have seen this, but only with ships being unable to enter water tiles of a CS. It appears very rare and to be a bug with the game. None of us were able to determine a way to resolve this within the active game.